# Using socket.io in reactjs lifecycle methods

Tags: reactjs

I am learning reactjs and am having issues updating a component when it receives a message via socket.io. It works when the component is initially created but every time after that it needs to be called twice before it displays the correct data.

1. For example I click a menu button and the component requests the data from the server. The server sends the result back and the component displays correctly. Because the component is being created from scratch it works perfectly.
2. I click another menu button, but the component is already created as above. The menu button requests data from the server and the server returns the result, but the component doesnt update and display it. HOWEVER clicking another menu button causes the component to display the previous result sent by the server (so the component is always one button click behind).

I understand why is isnt working (because of the async nature of web dev) but I have no idea how to get the react component to do what I intend. I have tired the various lifecycle methods. General improvements on my react code welcome.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import io from 'socket.io-client';
    const socket = io('http://localhost:8080/');

    import DataTable from './DataTable'


    const headers = [];
    const rows = [];

    export default class Form extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

        this.state = {
            headers,
            rows
        };

        this.sortData = this.sortData.bind(this);

    }

    sortData(column) {
        var data = this.state.rows.slice(); //copy data
        data.sort((a, b)  => {
            return a[column] > b[column]? 1: -1;

        });
        this.setState({rows: data});

    }

    _getData(){
        //Request the data from the server
        socket.emit('get_data', this.props.location.query.option);
    }

    _receiveData(){
    socket.on(`data_result`, data => {
        this.setState({rows: data,
        headers: Object.keys(data[0])});
     });
   }

    componentDidMount() {
        //Request the result from the server and then use the result to render to component. 
        this._getData();
        this._receiveData();
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    //Needed so the component reacts to new input after component creation (component receives a new this.props.location.query.option to send to the server). Doesn't work as needed as it doesn't re-render when it gets a response from the server.

        this._getData();
        this._receiveData();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <DataTable form={this.props.location.query.option}
                           headers={this.state.headers} rows={this.state.rows}
                           sortData={this.sortData}/>
            </div>
        );

    }

}
```

Comment: You are invoking _receiveData in the constructor, componentDidMount and componentWillRecieveProps. I would suggest making the call in componentDidMount once. You can also merge the two setState commands you have into one.Fix those and see if that helps your situation

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the code to include your suggestions, but only using componentWillRecieveProps stops the component ever updating after the initial creation. Hence I was trying to use componentWillRecieveProps to react to a new button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. During 'componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)' I wasnt making use of nextProps.

I had to change the _getData method to take a variable and pass in nextProps and not the current prop.

```
    _getData(option){
        socket.emit('get_data', option);
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        this._getData(this.props.location.query.option);
        this._receiveData();
    }

       componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if (nextProps.location.query.option != this.props.location.query.option) {
        this._getData(nextProps.location.query.option);
        this._receiveData();
    }
}
```